# Why is the field of fractions of a domain $R$ a flat $R$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I want to show  this lemma:

> Let $R$ be a domain. If $A$ is a torsion $R$-module, then $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R (K,A)\cong A$ where $\operatorname{Frac}(R)=Q$ and $K=Q/R$.

When I was reading this proof need to show $Q$ is flat and it back to this problem

> if $R$ is a domain with $Q=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, then $Q$ is flat $R$-module?

I don't know why $Q$ is flat. Can you help please?
 thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a short exact sequence of modules and localize it, it remains exact.

What is the relation between localizing a module and tensoring it with the field of fractions?

Comment: why if $0\to M\to N\to L\to 0$is exact sequence then $0\to M\otimes Q\to N\otimes Q$is exact?

Comment: Have you read my answer? :-|

Comment: I don't know localize!

Comment: Then ask for a clarification or an alternative explantion. Repeating your original question in a comment is somewhat confusing!

Comment: @parisa this answer deserves acceptation. if you are not familiar with localization you can add in your question that you prefer the answers not using localization

Comment: In any case, I suggest you read up on localization, parisa. It is slightly weird to know about flatness and Tor and not about localizations!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Old discussion but just wanted to comment that my graduate programs teaches the 'traditional' ring/module theory (focusing on all things noncommutative) in one course but reserves teaching about localizations until your introductory course in commutative algebra. So many of my fellow students (at one point myself included) knew much about flatness, ext, tor, and the like but nothing of localization other than vague comments that it was 'like' FOF and that we would see it later.

Answer (score 6):

*Mariano Suárez-Alvarez*'s answer is correct. I only add that in general $S^{-1}$ is exact:
Atiyah-Macdonald has:

[image]

and
[image]

The particular case is field of fraction of a domain