# notation $tA$ in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, torsion-groups

Currently, I am studying torsion group. Reading the lecture notes, I found this theorem

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $Q:= \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ with $K=Q/R$, then $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(K,A) \cong tA$ for all $R$-module $A$.

I figure out from the stackexchange question [Why field of fractions is flat?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259488/why-field-of-fractions-is-flat), if $A$ is a torion $R$-module, then $tA=A$, so is $tA$ stands for torion of $A$?  How one can define that?

As far as I know, the definition of my $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(A,B) = H_n(P_A \otimes_R B) = H_n(A \otimes_R P_B)$ which is a homology of tensor products between one objects and the projective resolution

Comment: Did you mean "torsion $R$-module?" "torion" is not a word, and you use it twice.

Comment: $tA$ is presumably the torsion elements of $A,$ $$tA=\{a\in A\mid \exists r\in R, ra=0\},$$ which is a submodule of $A.$ But I don't know if that is standard notation, so only the lecturer can tell you what they meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exact sequence $0\to R\to Q\to Q/R\to 0$, so tensoring with $A$ gives an exact sequence
$$Tor_1(Q,A)\to Tor_1(Q/R,A)\to R\otimes_R A\cong A\to Q\otimes_R A.$$
However, since $Q$ is a flat $R$-module, we have $Tor_1(Q,A)=0$, so
$$Tor_1(Q,A)=\ker(A\to Q\otimes_RA).$$
It is easy to see that this is exactly the torsion elements in $A$, as Thomas mentions.